# Google Account Logout from android app

Tags: android, android-activity, logout, google-signin

How can I logout from my app that have an option to sign in using google account?
logout is done from another activity.how can i achieve this?
please help..

Answer (score 0):

First make connection with Google like that write this code in onCreate method
   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

```
    GoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
            .build();
```

GoogleApiClient.connect();

then:

```
  Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(GoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {


                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            sessionManager.clearSession();
                            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Logout Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
```